# Observable Collection within a Property of Another Class

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

Suppose I have a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, where the one of the properties is a class whose members are `ObservableCollections`:

```
namespace Example
{
    public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private B _prop;
        public B Prop 
        {
            get { return _prop; }
            set 
            {
                _prop = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Prop");
            }
        }

        public A() { Prop = new B(); }

        //"Some Property" related Prop.words

    }

    public class B 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<String> words { get; set; }

        public B() { words = new ObservableCollection<String>(); }
    }

}
```

I am confused about how to notify when that property in class `A` when `Prop.words` changes.  In which class do I implement the handler from `INotifyCollectionChanged`?

EDIT: I didn't specify the context earlier, but I'm binding a WPF control on "Some Property"  that i need to update when the `Prop.words` changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If class A needs to be notified, then you have to ***hook CollectionChanged in Class A*** only. Do that in property setter of Prop.

Make sure to unhook the handler in case property B gets set with new value to avoid any memory leaks.

```
public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private B _prop;
    public B Prop
    {
        get { return _prop; }
        set
        {
            if(_prop != null)
                _prop.words.CollectionChanged -= words_CollectionChanged;
            _prop = value;
            if (_prop != null)
                _prop.words.CollectionChanged += words_CollectionChanged;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Prop");
        }
    }

    void words_CollectionChanged(object sender, 
                                 NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Notify other properties here.
    }

    public A() { Prop = new B(); }

    //Some Property related Prop.words

}
```

Comment: When you say "hook CollectionChanged in Class A", do you mean something like `_prop.words.CollectionChanged += SomeEvent`?

Comment: Right. I have already added code in answer. Isn't it that you want?

Comment: IMHO not a good idea: imagine you have an items control bound to the collection: each time the collection changes it will be entirely bound because we notify that it has changed entirely!

Comment: @Pragmateek - `each time the collection changes it will be entirely bound because we notify that it has changed entirely` - Where we notify that it changed entirely? OP want to update some property in class A when words collection changes. What notification you are talking about?

Comment: I've integrated it into my code and it's working now.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @RohitVats yep I've anticipated too much. :)

Answer (score 0):

The client of the `A` class should handle this.

IMHO raising `PropertyChanged` when the underlying collection changes is breaking the **functional contract** of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Moreover imagine you have an items control bound to the collection: each time the collection changes it will be entirely rebound because we notify that it has changed entirely, definitely not what you want!

```
A a = new A();
...
a.Prop.Words.CollectionChanged += ...
```

This is exactly what the WPF controls will do if you bind to the `Prop` properties.

Note that from a dogmatic OO design perspective this is breaking the Law of Demeter, so you may make the Words collection surface into your A type to avoid this, but this is another issue/debate.

Comment: I guess you have taken it completely other way. OP doesn't want to raise property changed for collection itself. He wants property changed to be raised for some other property in class A. So, itemsControl won't rebound entirely.